# Print the average sum of letters divided by words

Tags: python

```
def average_word_length(text):
    count = 0
    for letter in text:
        count += 1
    return count

text = "This is a brief note"
x = average_word_length(text)
print(x)
```

I have to print the average word length of the text: This is a brief note. The output has to be 3.2 (16 letters divided by 5 word. How can I get an output of 4?

Comment: I don't know what is your goal but since you are working with words you might want to use an NLP: https://www.nltk.org/

Comment: I would recommend reading [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) You'll get better answers, and understand them better, if you talk through what you've tried so far, and ask a specific question about the issues you're facing. (This is basically true of any Stack Overflow question, but especially so with homework.) And ultimately you'll learn more, too!

Answer (score 5):

First, create a list of words:

```
words = text.split()
```

Then, find the length of each word:

```
word_lengths = [len(word) for word in words]
```

Then, take its average:

```
avg_word_length = sum(word_lengths) / len(word_lengths)
```

Comment: How do I code that? I have to code this with a function

Answer (score -1):

```py
def average_word_length(text):
    words = text.split()  # ['This', 'is', 'a', 'brief', 'note'], len = 5
    # "".join(words)) = 'Thisisabriefnote', len = 16
    return len("".join(words)) / len(words)

print(average_word_length('This is a brief note'))
```

Alternative solution without `join` function:

```py
def average_word_length(text):
    words = text.split()  # ['This', 'is', 'a', 'brief', 'note'], len = 5
    # text.replace(' ', '') = 'Thisisabriefnote', len = 16
    return len(text.replace(' ', '')) / len(words)

print(average_word_length('This is a brief note'))
```

Comment: Thanks, is that also possible without the join function?

Comment: @Kariem see altenative solution